# OpenCV problems with Netbeans and Cygwin

Tags: c++, opencv, path, cygwin, netbeans-7

I have tried today for five hours to install OpenCV and run a simple program to check that it works. I have not been able to do this despite looking at several tutorials and youtube video's. Could anyone tell me firstly if there is a difference between using cygwin or mingw? Why is it so hard to link the OpenCV libraries to netbeans. I love the IDE but will have to use Visual Studio if I cant get it working tomorrow. I have not been able to find a tutorial that references opencv2.4.6 which is the latest version and netbeans 7.4. For anyone interested the cygwin version I down loaded was 1.7.25. The main problem I am having is finding out how to correctly link the OpenCV headers etc to netbeans. If anyone has made a record of how to do this then sharing it would be great. Maybe I'm going wrong with the system variables I'm just not sure. As said any help or directions to up to date tutorials would be a great help. I love Netbeans and want to keep using it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this post while trying to set up OpenCV with Netbeans 7.4 on windows 7.
After finally getting everything to work I wrote this guide: [OpenCV Netbeans C++ setup guide](http://maketheplanet.com/index.php/guides/89-installing-opencv-for-netbeans-7-4)

I was able to get all the libraries linked. Also the clean/Build and run works for my C++ opencv 2.4.7 app from netbeans 7.4.  Hope this can help anyone else who might want to use Netbeans for OpenCV coding.